# Get both output and return code of external program

Tags: import, interface, external-calls

`Run["program"]` will run an external program and return the return code.

`Import["!program", "String"]` will run the program and return the output as a string.

How can I get both the output and the return code?  I need a cross platform solution.

It would be nice (but not strictly necessary) to get stderr too.  Do we need J/Link to achieve this?

Comment: Is `Run["ls >> /tmp/ls.txt"]` what you want ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, but that's rather ugly and has its own problems.  For example, if I don't want to make a mess, I need to make sure I'm writing into the temp directory; if that has spaces in the path, I need to escape them; and so on

Comment: Can't you use a combination of `StringJoin` to build the command and `FileNameJoin` for the output ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, of course it's possible, but it's a lot of trouble.  Can you show off hand how to do it in a way which will work on all platforms and there won't be problems with spaces in file names or paths?  I think even `RunThrough` had a bug because it didn't handle spaces properly on Windows XP.

Comment: Not helpful: I did `Import["!bla ; echo $?"]` and knew that last part was the exit status, but that's very far from cross platform

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say `JLink` is one of the fastest ways to do this. Just use the `Runtime` to start a process executing your command and collect the exit code too:

```
<< JLink`

RunThroughWithExitCode[cmd_String] :=
 JavaBlock[Module[{ireader, istream, runtime, process, reader},
   LoadJavaClass["java.lang.Runtime"];
   runtime = Runtime`getRuntime[];
   process = runtime@exec[cmd];
   process@waitFor[];
   istream = process@getInputStream[];
   ireader = JavaNew["java.io.InputStreamReader", istream];
   reader = JavaNew["java.io.BufferedReader", ireader];
   {reader@readLine[], process@exitValue[]}
   ]]
```

And then you get

```
RunThroughWithExitCode["uname -a"]
(* {Linux lenerd 3.2.0-39-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP 
    Thu Feb 28 00:28:53 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux,
   0}
*)
```

The same approach can be used to catch the error stream of the `process`.

When you are on a system with a `bash`, you could collect everything in the system call itself. This is basically the same idea that was already suggested by @ssch

```
RunThroughWithExitCode2[cmd_String] :=
 ToExpression@Import[
 "!out=\"$(eval " <> cmd <> ")\";ret=$?;echo \"{\\\"${out}\\\",${ret}}\"", "String"]
```

This works too and gives a list of output and return value

```
RunThroughWithExitCode2["which math"]
(* {"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0.1/Executables/math", 0} *)
```

Comment: `output = {Rest@NestWhileList[
    reader@readLine[] &, "", # =!= Null &,
    1, Infinity, -1]
  , process@exitValue[]}` or similar to return all lines of the result (possibly want to `StringJoin` with "\n" inter-spaced)

Comment: @ssch In the version I tested here, I read all output too, but I wanted the function as small as possible. I think the rest can be adapted easily.

Comment: Agreed, very clear the way it is now!

Comment: Thank you, this spares me a lot of trouble and a lot of Java doc reading

Comment: @halirutan How would you change the Java code, `RunThroughWithExitCode`, so it gives the exit stream?

Comment: @Liam What is the *exit stream*? Or to ask different: what do you try to achieve?

Comment: Let me clarify if I run `RunThroughWithCode["dir"]` in Windows I get back `Java::excptn: "A Java exception occurred: "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program \"!echo \": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified "`  How do I get back both the stdout and stderror(I believe that is what there are called).  I referred to it as exit stream because that is what you called it in your question.

Comment: I read exit stream in your answer so I assumed that night be another stram that would contain errors other the output stream and the error code.  @halirutan here is an image of the error http://i.stack.imgur.com/RrdNy.png

Comment: @Liam Ahh, OK. Have a look at the API doc to [the Process class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). There you find similar to `getInputStream` the method `getErrorStream` which should give you what you want.

Comment: @halirutan Why did you use `getInputStream` instead of `getOutputStream`?  I would assume `getOutputStream` gives output. **The reason why I am asking:** In Windows to run multiline built in commands you need to run something like `type temp/file | powershell -Command -`, but as soon as I do that I no longer get the output with `getInputStream`, while `getOutputStream` seems to throw an Java error.  Here is my current code http://pastebin.com/u3PUvc5a if you have any ideas how to fix or adapt.

Comment: @Liam Because the output is the data you *send* to the process. This becomes clear when you [read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()). Unfortunately, I have not much experience with Windows.

Comment: This solution may cause the subprocess to deadlock if the output generated by the subprocess exceeds the pipe buffer size (which may be as low as 4 KB on certain platforms).

Comment: @sakra After all the code in my answer was nothing I have tested carefully or used in a real project. Please, if you have used it or found a safer alternative, feel free to edit my answer and add important information.

Answer (score 9):

For those who will encounter the same problem as mine (and OP's), I added this answer.

Mathematica now(since 10.0.0) has a new built-in function called `RunProcess` which does exactly what OP asked (including the standard error).